# how can i use SwipereFreshLayout on bottom in gridview?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I am using SwipereFreshLayout and it always seen on top of grid view, but I want to have this on bottom. How can i do this?

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/private_board"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_progress_bar"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#F4F4F4"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Code:

```
    swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

       swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

             new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                    }
                }, 2000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: wat u mean by use on bottom??

Comment: it's mean at the end of gridview..swiperefreshlayout always show on top but i want to show on bottom.

Comment: `swipeRefreshLayout` is a container and the `GridLayout` is the content present inside the `swipeRefreshLayout`. I d how the `swipeRefreshLayout` comes on the top when its just a container :-/

Comment: yes i know sir, but swiperefreshlayout work on top ,but same work i want to do on bottom.

Answer (score 0):

`SwipeRefershLayout` does not support `pull from bottom`. You need to implement your own for that. Take a look at this lib if it helps. https://bitbucket.org/andreyice/swiperefreshlayoutbottom. I have not used it. Or just look at the code and try to add your own functionality by extending them :)